# vb6 Const "App.Path"

Tags: vb6, path, constants

I have this code to const the Current Path :

```
Option Explicit
Const CurPath As String = App.Path 'not working and higlight ".Path" for error.

Private Sub Form_Load() 'just for test with Label1 Caption
Label1.Caption = CurPath
End Sub
```

i don't know whats wrong but it **does'nt work**, but i want to set constant for current path to use in many `SUB and Function`, any suggestion?

**NOTE:** i want this const stay in the *Form* and **NOT** in *Module*, and once again, i want this in **`const`**, because another const need this too.

Comment: Const will be evaluated at compile time, thereby it is not possible to assign it at run time. Why do you need Const at all? Make property with only Get method, it is enough read-only.

Comment: Another const can't read the property, that is the reason why i write **i want this in const**

Comment: @faid: Don't be stubborn, follow Arvo's advice, it is the correct solution Our application uses it that way throughout.

Comment: @faid: const can't read *anything* - it is set at compile time. Looks like your another const should be read-only property again. Maybe you are confusing VB Const keyword with C++ const modifier? They are different.

Comment: Okay, i'll try change it all with `Property Get`, maybe that is the solution :), After all my knowledge about const is poor. :(

Comment: App.Path isn't the "current" directory anyway, just the one the EXE is located in. The CurDir$() function provides the current directory. In the most degenerate case they are the same value, but many things can change the current directory during the run such as the shortcut the program was started from, code within the program, use of common dialogs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said you didn't want your Const in a module, but I would suggest using a method in a module. Placing a public method in a module makes it available to all the forms, and other modules of your application. Below is a function I wrote and added to a module that contains common methods that I use often. Whenever I begin a new project I automatically add this module.

```
Public Function AppPath() As String
   Dim sAppPath As String

   sAppPath = App.Path
   If Right$(sAppPath, 1) <> "\" Then  'check that I'm not in the root
      sAppPath = sAppPath & "\"
   End If

   AppPath = sAppPath

End Function
```

To use:

```
Private Sub Form_Load() 'just for test with Label1 Caption
Label1.Caption = AppPath
End Sub
```

Comment: you know, i actually just want to get current drive letter in const with App.Path, and i've set the current path with App.Path in the sub and not const it, btw, thanks, and maybe it is time for me to learn the module (hehehe, none of my projects using modules, because it just makes me confused "Newbie in VB6") ...